# Modification to Latin Square Design

Tags: experiment-design, latin-square

I have an experiment where I am having participants rate the readability of 10 different texts. I have 37 participants and I would like them to rate the readability for 6 texts each so that each text will be rated by at least 20 different people. However, I'm concerned about order effects in the presentation of the texts so I would like to use a Latin square design. Is there any way that I can modify the Latin square design so that I could present 6 texts to each participant rather than all ten?

Comment: Given it can't be balanced, can you say more about the exact conditions you need the design to satisfy?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_rectangle

Comment: Why not randomly assign texts? It isn't perfect control of reader-effects, but you can use a random intercept to estimate and account for the interreader variability.

Comment: This sounds like a cross-over study, maybe add the tag [tag:crossover-study]